# How to disable python interactive mode in vs code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ipython

I prefer to use [this](https://github.com/hoangKnLai/vscode-ipython) extension so I find very annoying that every time I write a code-cell or hit shift-enter VS-Code opens its internal interactive python console.
How to stop such a behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view your keyboard shortcuts using:

1. Click the *gear icon* in the lower left corner of the interface
2. Select **Keyboard Shortcuts** *(Ctrl + K + S)*

   [image]
3. Select Record Keys *(Alt + k)* on the right side of the input box

   [image]
4. Press the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and <kbd>ENTER</kbd> keys
5. View the functions bound to this shortcut key in the list

   [image]
6. Just delete what you don't want.

---

---

#### UPDATE

##### Uninstall `Jupyter` extension, you will not get any interactive window features.

[image]

*Don't forget to restart vscode after uninstalling*

Answer (score 0):

Change the keybinding for 'interactive.execute' in the Keyboard Shortcuts. To access keyboard shortcuts, press ctrl+shift+p and type 'keyboard'

Comment: That is fine for the shortcuts but when I type a code-cell in the editor (i.e. I write `# %%` in a Python file)  it is triggered the python interactive anyway as VS-Code automatically adds `Run Cell | Run Below | Debug Cell` in the file I am editing, which is something I don't want. To reproduce the issue is very easy: just create a new python file, and type `# %%`.

Comment: I am not sure how to disable it for the extension you have installed, but you would definetaly find some kind of option in vscode settings. Try searching for '# %%' or 'code cell' in the settings.